# PHP regex and preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that I need to match, which can be in various formats:

```
5=33
5=14,21
5=34,76,5
5=12,97|4=2
5=35,22|4=31,53,71
5=98,32|7=21,3|8=44,11
```

I need the numbers that appear between the equal sign (=) and pipe (|) symbol, or to the end of the line.  So in the last example I need `98`,`32`,`21`,`3`,`44`,`11` but I can't figure this out at all.  The numbers are not concrete, they can be any quantity of numbers.

I am just learning regex and preg_match and can't figure it out. I have no idea what I am doing.

Any help is *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- match only numbers
- requires the numbers to have a comma, vertial pipe, or end of string directly after the number, this prevents the numbers with an equals sign from being included.

`\d+(?=[,|\n\r]|\Z)` [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://www.rubular.com/r/VJQGupQmwF)

[image]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,|\n\r]                 any character of: ',', '|', '\n'
                             (newline), '\r' (carriage return)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Z                       before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

## Examples

**Samples**

With this expression the string `5=98,32|7=21,3|8=44,11` will return an array of strings:

```
[0] => 98
[1] => 32
[2] => 21
[3] => 3
[4] => 44
[5] => 11
```

---

## Or

You could just look for all numbers which are not followed by an equals sign

`\d+(?!=|\d)`   [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://www.rubular.com/r/vjfIi86TQA)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try below:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<==)[^|]*/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```